# Django. Как сделать проверку на уникальность поля в форме?

Tags: python, django

**Код в views.py:**

````
def add_ads(request):
    form_add_ads = AdvertisementForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_add = AdvertisementForm(request.POST)
        if form_add.is_valid:
            form_add.save(commit=False)
            form_add.instance.author = request.user
            form_add.instance.slug = get_slug(form_add.instance.title)
            form_add.save()
            return redirect('/ads/')
        else:
            form_add_ads = AdvertisementForm()

    return render(request, 'ads/add_ads.html', {'form_add_ads': form_add_ads})```

Код в models.py:
```class Advertisement(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(
        'Название объявления (должно быть уникальным, макс. символом 100)',
        max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField('Описание объявления')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    publish = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
        ordering = ['publish']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('ads_detail', args=[self.publish.year,
                                           self.publish.month,
                                           self.publish.day,
                                           self.slug])
````

Код в forms.py:

```
    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('title', 'content', 'category')
```

Суть вопроса: что мне добавить во въюху,
дабы проверить является ли заголовок уникальным?
Пробовал разными способами, в основном костыльными, ничего не работает.
Сама въюха добавляет статью в базу данных на основе формы, которая в свою очередь создана на основе модели.
На данный момент при попытке создать объявления с неуникальным заголовком возникает закономерная ошибка:
[image: ValueError at /ads/add_ads/]

PS: только начал учить django(2 недели), буду благодарен за любые замечания в коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`form_add.is_valid:`

`is_valid` - не свойство а метод. Добавьте скобки

Comment: Из-за обычной невнимательности ничего не работало...Спасибо Вам, помогли)

Answer (score 0):

Немного не понимаю для чего использовать уникальное описание и название, если в базе записи по id итак уникальны по умолчанию.
Но раз вопрос в другом, можно использовать метод `get_or_create`, который добавляет запись только в том случае, если такой записи ещё не существует иначе возвращает её из базы.
Документация: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

Пример:

```
adv = Advertisement.objects.get_or_create(title="Некий заголовок")
# Соответственно если нужно просто добавить запись, можно в переменную не записывать
Advertisement.objects.get_or_create(title="Некий заголовок")
```

Надеюсь правильно понял задачу)

Comment: Причиной неработоспособности стала моя невнимательность) Но спасибо за метод, возьму на заметку в будущем)

Comment: Ну с кем не бывает)